# Modify JSON, using Java

Tags: java, json

Hello I have app that is generating JSON data. When i open the route /someData I can see the JSON as I want, but when I save it in file or print it in Eclipse it adds Object name before the data:

> MyObjectSchema [latitude=45.95472, longitude=13.664836, Timezone=Europe,
>   currently={time=1459936800}...]

How can i delete MyObjectSchema that is before the list.
This is my code:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${fixedDelaySchema}", initialDelayString = "${initialDelaySchema}")
    public MyObjectSchema createMySchema() throws IOException {
        Map<String, ArrayList<MyObject>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<MyObject>>();
        map.put("data", (ArrayList<MyObject>) list1);
        Map<String, Long> map1 = new HashMap<String, Long>();
        map1.put("time", list1.get(0).getTime());

        MyObjectSchema obj1 = new MyObjectSchema();
        obj1.setLatitude(rf.getLatitude());
        obj1.setLongitude(rf.getLongitude());
        obj1.setTimezone(rf.getTimezone());
        obj1.setCurrently(map1);
        obj1.setHourly(map);
        System.out.println(obj1);
        listSchema.add(obj1);

        if (list1.get(0).getTime() == 1460019600) {
            String jsonString = obj1.toString();
            String path = "test.json";

            ObjectOutputStream outputStream = null;
            try {
                outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path));
                System.out.println("Start Writings");
                outputStream.writeObject(jsonString);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
                System.exit(0);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Error: " + e);
            }
        }
        return obj1;
    }
```

Comment: Did you autogenerate your `toString` method for `MyObjectSchema` with IntelliJ?  That's what it looks like that is (and that's what it looks like you're using to actually write out to a file).

Comment: Yes I have the toString method in MyObjectSchema pojo class.

Comment: When I delete toString() method from MyObjectSchema, the app is not generating. It shows only one row with @ and numbers.

Comment: ...So you're not really generating  JSON data.  You're generating data from the object instead.  There's a significant difference here. At a minimum you're missing a JSON marshaller - look into Jackson for a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced with similar problem in the past.
You can fix it like this:

```
String response = new Gson().toJson(listSchema);
 BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\file.json"));
      writer.write(response);
      writer.close();
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I need!

Answer (score 2):

`obj1.toString()` is calling the `toString()` method of your object `MyObjectSchema` which right now doesn't generate a JSON valid string. You could modify your `toString()` method in order to generate proper JSON by string concatenation, but I don't recommend it. Instead use a library like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) or [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to easily create JSON from your objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
Use Libraries like GSON.
To use Gson, declares the following dependency.

pom.xml
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>

// 1. Java object to JSON, and save into a file
gson.toJson(obj1, new FileWriter("D:\\test.json"));
```